# How to display observable in angular 2?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

Just trying out a ngrx-store sample app. In my component I have:

```
 <div *ngFor="#todo of todos">
        {{ todo.value }} 
 </div>
```

However the todos are not displayed after entering. This is the error I get:

```
Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known native property ("

      ********
      <div [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let todo of todos">
        {{ todo.value }} 
      </div>
"): App@8:11
```

How can I display the todos?
plunkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/yOw4qh4aZ5d9jhg235gD?p=preview

Comment: the code in your error message does not match the code you've listed above it. In particular, you have `ngFor="#todo of todos` instead of `ngFor="let todo of todos"`: This mistake will cause the error message you're getting. You **do not** need to import NgFor.

Comment: also, the plunkr you linked to is empty. And why does the title mention Observable? there is not an observable in sight here...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You forgot to `import` NgFor in your component. And register it in your components `directives:[ ]` property.

```
import { NgFor } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  directives: [NgFor]
})
```

Also if you are returning data async from an observable you will need to use the `async` pipe.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

Comment: @bierhier no it didn't. `NgFor` is a platform directive and **does not need to be imported this way** - this has been the case since the late alphas. You must've done something else (probably what I suggested in my comment on your question)

Comment: Please consider deleting this answer, it is flatly incorrect and there are already too many people confused about this... you, for instance :-P